# The caller does not have permission. 403

Tags: firebase, cloud

I need your help to understand how I can access my Cloud Storage.I use Unity, and read the documentation (I confess, not all).I do not have problems with upload the file to storage. I save audio files there, for recognition with Google Cloud Speech Api, using the HTTP request on this: https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize?key= + MySpeechApiKey

I am trying to send this:

```
"{"config": {"encoding":"LINEAR16","sampleRateHertz":44100,"languageCode":"ru-RU","maxAlternatives":1,"profanityFilter":false,"speechContexts":[{"phrases":[""]}],"enableWordTimeOffsets":false},

"audio":{"uri":"gs://calm-vine-195513.appspot.com/2018.7.28_10_1_16_382.flac"}}
```

And i get request:

```
{

    "error": {

        "code": 403,

        "message": "The caller does not have permission",

        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"

    }

}
```

It is worth considering that in the Firebase I made a rule:

```
service firebase.storage {

    match /b/{bucket}/o {

        match /{allPaths=**} {

            allow read, write;

        }

    }

}
```

I found a couple of tips that say that I need some kind of service account. How can i do that?Do I need in request URI to add some key or what?

Comment: I do not understand how I should open full access? I do not care that anyone can access. I indicated in the request link to an example from Google:
"gs: //cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"

AND THIS WAS WORKED! But how can I make the same access as they do?
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it the following way:

1) You must have **gcloud** and **gsutil** installed

2) Then run **gcloud init** in command prompt. Here you must configure the configuration

3) Run **gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://*your_bucket***

It worked for me =)